# Changing Row Color On Click PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been trying to work this for days, with no avail so hopefully you guys can help me.

I've got a custom `QSqlTableModel` that has this as it's data function:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    #Formats Cells according to data in them
    if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        if index.column() == 2:
            text = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, self.index(index.row(), 2), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

            if text.split():
                if not re.search(r'start|Z[NARXTFEISL]|gv', text.split()[0], re.I):
                    return QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop
                else: return QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft
            else: pass
        else: return QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft

    if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if 'MILESTONE' in  QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, self.index(index.row(), 2), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)


    return QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)
```

None of it's really relevant to the question except for the `BackgroundRole` block. What I'm trying to do is when I right click on the `tableview` a context menu appears:

```
menu = QMenu()
stepx = menu.addAction('Mark Step as Executed')
stepdx = menu.addAction('Clear Step Execution')

action = menu.exec_(self.tableView.mapToGlobal(pos))
index = self.model.index(self.tableView.rowAt(pos.y()), 2)

if action == stepx:
    logging.info(' Executed Step: ' + str(self.tableView.rowAt(pos.y()) + 1))
    self.model.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

All I'm trying to do is when I click `"Mark Step as Executed"` on my context menu, I want the row (or even the cell, I'll take anything at this point) to change to red.

Nothing of what I'm doing is working and I'm hoping someone can assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create a field in the database table and use as a flag to change the background colors, but if you can not make that change in the database you must create a new role. and then we will use that role to make the necessary changes, for this we will save the flag in a dictionary, the key of the dictionary will be the id since these do not change.

```
class SqlTableModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    ExecuteRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None, db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase()):
        QtSql.QSqlTableModel.__init__(self, parent, db)
        self.d = {}

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == self.ExecuteRole:
            _id = self.getId(index)
            if _id in self.d.keys():
                return self.d[_id]
            return False

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if self.data(index, self.ExecuteRole):
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
            if 'MILESTONE' in QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, self.index(index.row(), 2), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)

        return QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)

    def getId(self, index):
        ix = self.fieldIndex("id")
        return self.data(self.index(index.row(), ix), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == self.ExecuteRole:
            self.d[self.getId(index)] = value
            return True
        return QtSql.QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def roleNames(self):
        rn = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.roleNames(self)
        rn[self.SelectRole] = QtCore.QByteArray(b'execute')
        return rn
```

The above only change a selected item until it is refreshed manually, but this behavior is not the one that is wanted to do so the model `dataChanged()` signal must be issued.

```
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        stepx = menu.addAction('Mark Step as Executed')
        stepdx = menu.addAction('Clear Step Execution')

        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action == stepx:
            if self.model():
                index = self.model().index(self.rowAt(pos.y()), 2)
                self.model().setData(index, True, SqlTableModel.ExecuteRole)
                self.model().dataChanged.emit(self.model().index(index.row(), 0),
                                              self.model().index(index.row(), self.model().columnCount()-1),
                                              [QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole])
```

The current implementation has the advantage of being deselected if we change the state from True to False.

```
self.model().setData(index, False, SqlTableModel.ExecuteRole)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This works in the sense that it does indeed change the color, and I love that I can revert the color. However, it seems to change the entire table red. Not just the selected row. Why would that be?

Comment: Are you sure? In my test, just change the selected row, try the following example and let me know if you have the same error: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/150e981878122e171bd25dc470781a87

Comment: If you share your project to check where you have made a mistake. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct please.

Comment: Your example works, but mine doesn't. I believe it has something to do with how I'm initializing `qTableView`. But here is my project so far. https://github.com/aseylys/sView EDIT: And I marked you as answered because you did, it's my programs inability to cooperate that is the problem

Comment: @aseylys  How do I load the database? I do not see any data in the tableview.

Comment: `File->Open Script`, sorry, I haven't gotten around to the README yet.

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a primary key in your table, but I think that `Row #` can be used by changing: `ix = self.fieldIndex("id")` to `ix = self.fieldIndex("Row #")`