# Adapting a PyQt QSqlTableModel to color rows, if they include a specific entry in a column, while retaining editing functionality

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently working a small database visualization using PyQt. As the visualization should include edit functionality on some columns, I wanted to use PyQts QSqlTableModel.

Basically a new dataset is given and compared to the existing database.
The entries not yet in the database should be displayed as well as the entries, which have a corresponding entry in the database already.
The new entries with changes are flaged as 'new' and the current entries are flaged as 'old'.

The Table is setup as follows:

| Show_Again | Annotation | Status(flag) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 or null | text or null | old, new, null | ... |
| 1 or null | text or null | old, new, null | ... |

Now I was asked to highlight the entries with Status='new' in red and if possible highlight where the old and new entries differ.

The regular background coloring I tried to implent by adapting a [solution a found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410120/changing-row-color-on-click-pyqt).

While the background is now colored red, the programm crashes as soon as I try to enter any value in the first three columns.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\Workspace_Arbeit\Pruefungsdb_Visualizer\minimum_viable_code.py", line 400, in data
    if 'new' in QSqlTableModel.data(self, self.index(index.row(), 2), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

This the current code:

```
class SqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    ExecuteRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None, db = QSqlDatabase()):
        super(QSqlTableModel,self).__init__(parent, db)

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if 'new' in QSqlTableModel.data(self, self.index(index.row(), 2), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)

        if role==QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return super(SqlTableModel, self).data(index, role)

        return super(SqlTableModel, self).data(index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
```

I have also tried other solutions, that suggested to use an ItemStyleDelegate, which I unfortunately did not get to work.
Although I suspect it would have created different problems as I currently use an ItemDelegate to prevent editing on any column beyond the third.

Comment: The fact that you want to prevent editing is completely unrelated to the background, so it won't create any problem with the delegate. Note that you actually don't even need a delegate if you just want to limit editing to a certain column index. That said, please paste the *full* error, we (and you) need to know *what* caused the problem, not just it's type: I suggest you to run the program in a terminal or prompt, so that you can have the full traceback (which IDEs aren't always able to show).

Comment: Hi,
first of all thank you for reading my question.
I added the traceback at the end. Sorry I forgot that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, you're trying to do find `new` in the result of `data()`.

But, as you also reported in your scheme, that column could also have `null` values, which in python terms corresponds to `None`, that is clearly not an *iterable* type.

First you need to get the value, *then* you check if the value is a string and it contains "new". Note that the whole `data()` implementation you did is almost unnecessary, since you're just returning the default behavior. Override only what you actually need to change, and leave the rest as it is.

```py
class SqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            value = super().data(index.siblingAtColumn(2), Qt.DisplayRole)
            if isinstance(str, value) and 'new' in value:
                return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        return super().data(index, role)
```

Note that you could do the same even with a delegate:

```
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        state = index.siblingAtColumn(2).data()
        if isinstance(state, str) and 'new' in state:
            opt.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
```

This has absolutely no relation with the fact that you want to prevent editing, which you could do independently even at model level:

```
class SqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    # ...
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if index.column() >= 3:
            flags &= ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return flags
```